# Why does a process i executed die when the terminal is killed

Tags: bash, scripts

Why does a process i executed from a shell script terminate when i kill the script/terminal that called the script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every process has to have a parent process (to collect exit status, at the very least). see `man 2 wait`. If a parent process dies, its children are sent a `SIGHUP` signal (see `man 7 signal`). `SIGHUP` is a catchable signal, but if the child doesn't catch it, the default action is to kill the child process.

See `man nohup` to keep things going.

Comment: I see thank you very much

Comment: Either nohup or setsid will do. I prefer the last one

Answer (score 0):

To [execute a background job and keep it running](https://www.maketecheasier.com/run-bash-commands-background-linux/) after terminal is closed use:

```
nohup command &>/dev/null &
```